# How to check for memory loss

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am about to write a (very) large code for a scientific project, where a large numbers of allocatable arrays will be used. Is there an intrinsic fortran function or maybe a compiler flag which I can used which checks that all allocatable variables have been correctly deallocated? I am using `gfortran`.

Comment: You have the `allocated` function which you can use yourself to check the allocation status of an entity, and the language standard requires that the compiler take care of deallocation when an allocated entity goes out of scope (subject to exceptions for `save`d entities).  It's not impossible, not even terribly difficult, to write code to leak memory (especially if your code makes use of pointers to allocatable arrays) but it can generally be avoided.

Comment: Memory leaks with `allocatable` arrays are not possible. That's the main reason why to use them in the first place. You should only worry about `pointer` arrays or if you know you must free some no longer needed global array.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark so deallocating arrays is "optional" in the sense that if you don't do it, the compiler does it for you? that's nice

Comment: You could try to use `valgrind` to detect memory leaks.

Comment: Yes, that's about it.  It is nice.

Answer (score 0):

gcc and therefore also gfortran can use the AddressSanitizer library to detect memory leaks. This can be enabled using the `-fsanitize=address` option.

The output will then be similar to what `valgrind` produces:

```
==26339==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 144 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f46fad68510 in malloc (/usr/lib64/libasan.so.4+0xdc510)
    #1 0x407754 in __sectiontest_MOD_constructor /users/tiziano/work/tests/fortran/cp2k_input_parser/recursive_mwe_alternative/recursive_mwe.f90:27
    #2 0x403939 in __sectiontest_MOD_demo /users/tiziano/work/tests/fortran/cp2k_input_parser/recursive_mwe_alternative/recursive_mwe.f90:95
    #3 0x408564 in MAIN__ /users/tiziano/work/tests/fortran/cp2k_input_parser/recursive_mwe_alternative/recursive_mwe_prog.f90:5
    #4 0x4085a4 in main /users/tiziano/work/tests/fortran/cp2k_input_parser/recursive_mwe_alternative/recursive_mwe_prog.f90:2
    #5 0x7f46f9d8ef89 in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x20f89)

Direct leak of 96 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f46fad68510 in malloc (/usr/lib64/libasan.so.4+0xdc510)
    #1 0x407754 in __sectiontest_MOD_constructor /users/tiziano/work/tests/fortran/cp2k_input_parser/recursive_mwe_alternative/recursive_mwe.f90:27
    #2 0x403d72 in __sectiontest_MOD_demo /users/tiziano/work/tests/fortran/cp2k_input_parser/recursive_mwe_alternative/recursive_mwe.f90:95
    #3 0x408564 in MAIN__ /users/tiziano/work/tests/fortran/cp2k_input_parser/recursive_mwe_alternative/recursive_mwe_prog.f90:5
    #4 0x4085a4 in main /users/tiziano/work/tests/fortran/cp2k_input_parser/recursive_mwe_alternative/recursive_mwe_prog.f90:2
    #5 0x7f46f9d8ef89 in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x20f89)

Indirect leak of 144 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f46fad68510 in malloc (/usr/lib64/libasan.so.4+0xdc510)
    #1 0x405fec in __sectiontest_MOD_section_assign /users/tiziano/work/tests/fortran/cp2k_input_parser/recursive_mwe_alternative/recursive_mwe.f90:50
    #2 0x408237 in __sectiontest_MOD_constructor /users/tiziano/work/tests/fortran/cp2k_input_parser/recursive_mwe_alternative/recursive_mwe.f90:30
    #3 0x403d72 in __sectiontest_MOD_demo /users/tiziano/work/tests/fortran/cp2k_input_parser/recursive_mwe_alternative/recursive_mwe.f90:95
    #4 0x408564 in MAIN__ /users/tiziano/work/tests/fortran/cp2k_input_parser/recursive_mwe_alternative/recursive_mwe_prog.f90:5
    #5 0x4085a4 in main /users/tiziano/work/tests/fortran/cp2k_input_parser/recursive_mwe_alternative/recursive_mwe_prog.f90:2
    #6 0x7f46f9d8ef89 in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x20f89)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 384 byte(s) leaked in 3 allocation(s).
```

As stated before in the comments, memory leaks should not be occurring with allocatables. On the other hand has experience shown that there can be compiler bugs which can cause memory leaks nevertheless.